# Checking skit translation

Tags: sentence

I am trying to make a skit with a group and this is what they have decided they want the beginning to be.

We are very new to Japanese, taking a compressed class this summer and are having trouble composing the sentences correctly.

Would anyone mind checking it out and see how we did in our translations?

The things in bold I am particularly concerned about.

> *N trips*
>
> N: いたい
>
> A: だいじょぶですか。
>
> B: びょういんのでんわをかけますか。 Do you need me to call an ambulance?
>
> **N: いいえ、びょういんのでんわをかけません。だいじょうぶです。No I don't need an ambulance. I'm fine.**
>
> N: ええと、はじめましたキリスですよろしくおねがいします。
>
> **A: リチですこれわジエイソンくんです。私のともだちです。I am Rich. This is (my friend) Jason.** This doesn't even say what i want. I believe it says, "I am Rich, this is Jason. At the very least I think the last line should be　私はジエイソンくんのともだちです。
>
> B:ともだちじゃないです。
>
> A：eeh?
>
> **B:じょだんです。** ごしゅっしんは **I am joking**, where do you come from?　 I would like this to be more natural like i am obviously joking perhaps
>   じょだんです,じょだんです?
>
> N:カナダです。
>
> A/B: そですね。

Comment: ask for tl check on hinative or Lang9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ええと、はじめましたキリスですよろしくおねがいします。

```
Suggestion: ええと、はじめまして。キリスです。よろしくおねがいします。
```

> A:リチですこれわジエイソンくんです。私のともだちです。

This would mean, "I'm Rich. This is Jason. He is my friend."

Don't use "kore" for a person, use "kochira". Also, beware of わ.
は is the correct hiragana for "wa" particle usage.

"私はジエイソンくんのともだちです" would mean, "I am Jason's friend."

```
Suggestion: "My name is Rich. This is my friend Jason."
わたしのなまえはリチです。こちらはわたしのともだち、ジェイソンです。
```

> B:じょだんです。 ごしゅっしんは

```
Suggestion: じょうだんだよ。ごしゅっしんは？
```

This still sounds unnatural to me to have these two right next to each other. I fixed the hiragana spelling of joudan and changed it to "da yo". If you two are friends you should use the casual copula and "yo" for emphasis.

> N:カナダです。

```
Suggestion: カナダからきました。(I came from Canada.)
```

> A/B: そですね。

`Suggestion: そうですか。`

Sou desu ne implies that you already knew he came from Canada, and you are agreeing with them.

Sou desu ka means that you didn't know before, "Is that so?"